# Adobe Illustrator arced text gets distorted after rotating

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, technique

Whenever I try `effect->warp->arc...` I can arc my text, but when I try to rotate it (say by -30 degrees) the text gets very distorted -- especially at the end point. Matters are worse if I try to rotate by a higher percentage (say -60 degrees).

I played around with countless vertical/horizontal distortion combinations, but the only way I found around this problem was by rasterizing the text first then rotating. However, this introduced its own set of problems because now I'm not in vector space anymore and I lost a good deal of fidelity in the process.

### Question

Is there a fool-proof way to arc text and then safely rotate it as desired without having to worry about distortion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead rotating, apply a new effect: go to menu Effect → Distort & Transform → Transform and set a rotation angle

[image]